# Does "We couldn't have heard it better" mean a possibility too?

Tags: grammar

We couldn't have heard it better.

What does the sentence mean?
I think, it means that 
either we DID NOT hear it so well in the past (subjunctive) OR 
we might have heard it so well (possibility).

Did I understand it correctly?  Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: The *meaning* is ambiguous - it might be extolling the *content* quality of what we heard (it couldn't have been ***better expressed***) or the clarity with which we heard it (because the speaker had a good PA system, we were well-positioned within the auditorium, etc.). There are *no* implications for whether we had heard it on any *other* occasion in the past - simply that *on the specific occasion being referenced*, it would not have been possible for us to have heard it any better.

Answer (score 1):

It means "It would not have been possible for us to have heard it any better".

This could be an exaggeration. Perhaps to be polite

> I'm sorry that seats I got you for the opera were at the back of the theatre. Could you hear it okay?
>   Don't worry we couldn't have heard it better!

The second speaker might be exaggerating, to reassure the first speaker.

It does not mean that the person has heard it in the past, only on this specific occasion it would not have been possible to hear it any better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer.   The example dialogue you wrote really helped me a lot.   Thanks.